# Where maven is installed (eclipse plugin)

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have M2Eclipse plugin installed on my eclipse, and now I am reading a book that says to use the mvn command, I think that I could use eclipse IDE to follow the book, but I want to know a little more about maven. Of course, the command "mvn" is not recognized, I need to edit my PATH variable.

I googled where is maven installed, and the answer is that it is an apache tool and the path is where you want to unzip the package.

BUT, what if I don´t want to install the apache project?? Is there any other option, because how I say at the beginning, I have M2Eclipse plugin installed, so I image that the executable file must to be in some folder into the plugin eclipse path... or does it use only java jar libraries without a binary??

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M2E is a plugin in Eclipse and not Maven. You are using an embedded Maven version which is part of Ecilpse. You should always install Maven to be useable via command line cause there are difference between M2E/Eclipse and command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any mvn goal by clicking on a maven project, than right click and select Run As -> Maven Build... and type any goal you want.